# SwiftUI @Published properties - why does it leave traces in memory? Is this a memory leak?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am developing a swift UI project with Viper architecture.
The presenter has an observable object where all states are kept.
While the view is created, I inject the observable presenter into the view.

When I'm going to read a state. This is how it arrives.

```
presenter.state.isEnable
or
presenter.isEnable
```

Everything is working. If I close the view all viper components and all views are cleared from memory.

The problem is, obviously only traces of @Published values remain. Does anyone know the reason for this?

Example View Init Code:

```
let viewController = ExampleUIHostingController(rootView: ExampleSwiftUIView(presenter: presenter))
self.present(controller, animated: true)
```

Example Presenter Code:

```
final class ExamplePresenter: ObservablePresenter {
    @Published var datasource: [Items] = []
    // OR
    @Published var states: ViewStates = ViewStates()
}
```

Example View Code:

```
struct ExampleViewView<T: ObservablePresenter>: View where T.ViewStates == ExampleStates  {
    @ObservedObject var presenter: T

    var body: some View {
        if !presenter.isReminderActive {
           Color.red
        }
    }
}
```

In such an environment, if I close a presented view.
All components are removed from memory. Except for @Published property keypaths.

Xcode memory debug ss: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETr17.jpg)

Comment: I recommend learning the SwiftUI architecture instead

Comment: I've seen similar issues with many architectures including TCA. Is there a specific example/tutorial you can suggest?

Comment: I recommend the WWDC videos to learn the SwiftUI architecture, try Data Essentials in SwiftUI from WWDC 2020 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/ if you try to apply a different architecture like Viper, TCA, MVVM etc to SwiftUI you'll have major problems.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll watch it again. But that's a very general answer for a specific question :)
And I encountered similar problems in many examples made with architecture.
I'm not even sure if this is an issue. It takes up very little memory and does not retain cycles between objects. I'm looking for a short answer.

Comment: SwiftUI (and Swift) are designed to use value types thats why the View that stores the state is a struct. And the View structs are in a hierarchy that also does depedency tracking so only the body funcs that reference changed values get updated. If you centralise state in one object then you are giving all that performance up and you wouldn't be able to use the deep linking or state restoration modifiers either.

Comment: I agree 100% with what you said. Very true.
The code I shared above is not my real build.
Not monitored by the whole presenter view. When the View is initialized, it receives a presenter reference but does not follow it.

Comment: The view with the presenter allocates the separated state objects send the child's views. So the view is not affected by all events.
The sample codes may have misled you. In all cases, @Published values continue to be traced in memory.  You can see it with https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETr17.jpg

Comment: It would not surprise me if this is "by design" in the system frameworks.  Key paths are very much like selectors in Objective-C or Atoms in Erlang and Elixir.  Those systems keep tables of constants that are allocated at runtime and preserved for the lifetime of the process. In Elixir the atoms can be allocated dynamically, at runtime, and it's possible to over-fill the atom table. For the key path they're usually static in the code so you'd have to write code with a *lot* of them for it to be a significant memory impact.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your patient answers. :)

Comment: I can not fully understant how the screenshot with the keypaths references is related to memory leaks from you View. Is that because if you run your app without displaying that view you do not see anything in the memory traces?

Comment: In fact, the situation is this;
The keypaths in the screenshot I shared are valuable references inside the screen I closed.

My app is UIKit in general. I am presenting a popup, using the uihostingcontroller in one place. I then turn it off.
Nothing of the related module can be displayed in memory debug.
Except for the keypaths of the properties which I listen to as @Published.

However, before opening this popup, the keypaths did not exist in memory. I thought they had to go when they closed. Of course, I'm not sure about that. :)